# Generating randoms numbers in a certain range for common lisp

Tags: random, common-lisp

I'm doing some homework and for one part I have to generate random numbers in the range 10 - 80. I know (random 80) will return a number less than 80 but how do I get it to get the numbers to be above 10 as well?

Answer (score 10):

Hint: (+ 1 (random 80)) will give you a number between 1 and 80 inclusive.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but when i try (+ 10(random 80)) I'll get values above 80

Comment: @Thomas: So you have a random number between 0 and 69 inclusive. How do you turn it into a random number between 10 and 80 inclusive? By adding...

Comment: @Thomas: I was trying to give a hint and let you figure out the details for yourself :-)

Comment: Next Hint: (+ 10 (random 10)) will return you values from 10 to 19 :)

Answer (score 3):

This code will give you random numbers from 10 to 80:

```
(+ 10 (random 71))
```

even better, try this general formula:

```
(defun random-from-range (start end)
  (+ start (random (+ 1 (- end start)))))
```